# Bat file to create a folder with the date is not adding the day?

Tags: batch-file, directory-structure

So I'm trying to get this BAT to create a folder with date, I've tried around 5 different variants and all of them created an extra folder, so far the  best one I've used is

Currently what I'm using (Not my code, got it off another thread)

```
REM Create a folder using the current date.  If such a folder already 

exists, append a number to make it unique.
@ECHO OFF
for /F "tokens=2-5 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do (
set Day=%%j
set Month=%%i
set Year=%%k
)

set Path=D:\share\Backup\Data %Year%-%Month%-%Day%
set /a inx=2

:LOOP
IF NOT EXIST "%Path%" GOTO CREATE
set Path=%~1\%Year%-%Month%-%Day% (%inx%)
set /a inx+=1
if %inx% gtr 9 goto :END REM Eh, giving up.
goto LOOP
:END

:CREATE
md "%Path%"
:END
```

This creates this directory: "D:\share\Backup\Data -04-17" as you can see it doesn't apply the day. Can someone help me modify this so the day works.

EDIT: The date for the the example should be the 23rd April 2017 or 23-04-17

EDIT 2: Changed the tokens as suggested, see below for working BAT

```
    REM Create a folder using the current date.  If such a folder already exists, append a number to make it unique.
@ECHO OFF
for /F "tokens=1-5 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do (
set Day=%%i
set Month=%%j
set Year=%%k
)

set DataPath=D:\share\Backup\Data %day%-%month%-%Year%
set /a inx=1

:LOOP
IF NOT EXIST "%DataPath%" GOTO CREATE
set DataPath=D:\share\Backup\Data %day%-%month%-%Year% (%inx%)
set /a inx+=1
if %inx% gtr 9 goto :END REM Eh, giving up.
goto LOOP
:END

:CREATE
md "%DataPath%"
:END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sir. 'tis the **year** that is missing as the created date is *missing*-month-*idunno*

Without knowing what your date format is, guidance is difficult. Perhaps changing your `tokens` may help. Currently, token 2 is assigned to `%%i`, 3 to `%%j`, 4 to `%%k`. Itry using `tokens=1-5` and observe which elements get assigned to `%%i`..`%%m` using `echo %%i+%%j+%%k+%%l+%%m` which will allow you to select the parts you want.

`path` is a logcal but very poor choice as a variable name since `path` is a reserved variable which tells windows where to find executable that aren't found in the current directory.